# No entry for / in /etc/fstab

Tags: filesystem, mount, fstab

I can't find an entry for mounting "/" in /etc/fstab (I was hoping to set commit value to something big because my HDD is pretty slow):

```
[.../fest]$ cat /etc/fstab
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
/dev/sda3    /media/megahard    ntfs-3g    defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0    0

/mnt/2Gb.swap  none  swap  sw  0 0


[.../fest]$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.10 \n \l
```

Netbook Remix, installed with chroot from Wubi (it's not Wubi, it's just installed from it)

Comment: Please add the output of `mount`.

Comment: or <code>df</code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `fstab` entry would look like this:

```
UUID=01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef  /  auto  errors=remount-ro  0 1
```

Replace the uuid value by the one for your system, which you can find out by running `cat /proc/cmdline`. Copy whatever is after `root=` into the first column of the `fstab` line, either `UUID=01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef` or `/dev/sdz99`.

Comment: awesome, seems to not crash anything